¿Como puedo eliminar automaticamente una columna dependiendo de la fila que elimine google sheets?
Tengo el siguiente problema. Como puedo borrar una columna de una fila x. Por ejemplo borro la fila D9 y necesito que tambien se borre automaticamente  la columna I9 y J9.


Hola. La pregunta no se entiende. En I5 y en J5 no hay nada. ¿Qué es lo que se supone se debe borrar? Indica además que has investigado/intentado y qué problemas o errores tienes. Y qué herramienta estás usando, si Google Apps Script u otra.

Estimado estoy utilizando google apps script. Por ejemplo borro la fila D9 y necesito que tambien se borre automaticamente la columna I9 y J9.

@A.Cedano. Estimado, lo que pasa que estoy realizando una hoja2 con importrange. Estoy obteniendo algunos valores de una hoja1. El tema es que en la nueva hoja2 agregue dos columnas que son despacho y gastos. Pero al modificar la hojaq original tambien se modifica la hoja2. Pero necesito que se borre esa fila que se modifico los datos de despacho y gastos. Tengo ese problema.

¿Y cuál es el código que está usando para hacer lo que describe?

Eso es lo que estoy intentando hacer porque hasta el momento no se me ocurre como puedo hacerlo. Estaba pensando apps script google sheets onedit pero hay estoy atrapado
